# Распределение трафика между серверами

Tags: dns, трафик

Вообще встал вопрос, когда пользователей на сайте стало больше 1-го т онлайна. Как в общих чертах распределить трафик я представляю, но мне нужно бы конкретнее понять, что использовать для этого, что прикупить. На моих руках сейчас есть пару компов, сеть 100 мб.сек и руки. Буду благодарен Вашей помощи, так как в администрировании серверов не очень разбираюсь. Хотя почитав пару статей, понял, что тут замешан DNS...

Comment: Ну собственно да, самое простое решение - для вашего домена сделать две `A` записи с ip адресами ваших серверов. клиенты примерно поровну будут приходить на один и второй. Стоит понимать, что любой клиент в любой момент времени может сам перейти с одного на другой. поэтому если вам надо поддерживать какую то информацию о сессии это надо отдельно продумать, что бы любой из северов мог получить нужную информацию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это можно сделать при помощи DNS. Для этого нужно на NS, обслуживающих домен вашего сайта, добавить столько А записей, сколько серверов у вас должно обслуживать запросы. В этих записях нужно указать IP адреса этих серверов.

Но подобную задачу можно так же реализовать и при помощи nginx. Вы можете принимать все запросы nginx'ом, а далее он сам будет распределять их по другим серверам. Сделать это можно при помощи директив `upstream` и `proxy_pass`. Вначале укажите сервера, на которые будут распределяться запросы:

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.0.1    weight=5;
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 backup;
    server backend2.site.net;
}
```

Параметр `weight` позволяет задать "вес" сервера (по-умолчанию = 1), параметр `backup` означает что на сервер будут приходить запросы только если недоступны остальные сервера. Кроме того, есть возможность управлять параметрами, отвечающими за определение сервера как недоступного.

После того, как вы описали группу серверов директивой `upstream` - используйте её следующим образом:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```

---

Описание директивы [`upstream`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)

Описание директивы [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю все об этом. Был бы рад, если бы кинули какие нибудь еще статейки, который могли бы понадобиться по этой теме. Конкретно по серверу, и nginx. Ах да и по возможности, если конечно не затруднит, фильтрация запросов, может кто нибудь уже выставлял подобное. Другими словами "Для обхода ддос".